# How to remove an email from a string with JavaScript (GTM)

Tags: javascript, email, google-tag-manager

This might sound quite simple and since I'm not as experienced as I would like handling javascript, I want to remove an email from a string, actually is an error message while trying to login or sign up.

My errors look like this:

The following email xxxx@gmail.com is incorrect
Invalid Data
Must close the current session
Mail already registered
...

So the idea is to remove the email from the first error, and if there is no email present then leave the other errors as they are now.

I found this code to detect if there is an email in a string but can't find a way to make it work "([^.@\s]+)(\.[^.@\s]+)*@([^.@\s]+\.)+([^.@\s]+)"

I just want to send the data to google analytics, and I'm trying to avoid sending personal data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another option would be to send an event to GA that is triggered by that particular error message or error event. This way you avoid having to Javascript a way of removing a string with regex and you can customise the data (event category, action, label) yourself, and you definitely avoid PII issues.

Answer (score 4):

`"([^.@\s]+)(\.[^.@\s]+)*@([^.@\s]+\.)+([^.@\s]+)"` is a regular expression. It matches everything that looks like an email. You can use it with the `replace()` and `search()` JavaScript functions, you need to delimit the expression with two `/`.

Example:

```js
var myString = "Hello, my email is blabla@blabla.com";

// Check if there is an email
if(myString.search(/([^.@\s]+)(\.[^.@\s]+)*@([^.@\s]+\.)+([^.@\s]+)/) !== -1){
    console.log("There is an email !");
    // Remove it...
    myString = myString.replace(/([^.@\s]+)(\.[^.@\s]+)*@([^.@\s]+\.)+([^.@\s]+)/,"");
    console.log(myString); // Hello, my email is 
}
```

Good tutorial about JavaScript regular expressions: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: Thank you, the string work really well, even includes hyphen and underscores. I'm about to publish it now and see how it goes.